# Transit visa rules in Dubai airport

Tags: transit-visas, pakistani-citizens, dxb, ecuadorian-citizens

My uncle is traveling from Dubai to Amsterdam and then to Quito. He is citizen of Ecuador and Pakistan, currently in Pakistan. He will arrive at 5 AM in Dubai from Lahore and leave Dubai at 11:55 PM on the same day.

I want to know how long he can stay in Dubai airport without visa. He will travel by KLM airlines from Dubai to Amsterdam and then from Amsterdam to Quito. Does he need a visa in Dubai?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? transit visa rules? because the length of the layover will be showing on the ticket, we do not have a copy of the ticket to tell.

Comment: Sir i m saying that he is coming from Lahore to Dubai then he my uncle will have to travel in klm airlines on 7 july 11.55pm i m asking that if he arrives Dubai from Lahore at 5am 7 July then how much he can stay on dubai airport how much he can stay after arriving from Lahore to Dubai on Dubai airport

Comment: So plz tell us how much he can wait if he arrives at 5am morning on Dubai airport but flight is late night at 11.55 pm i m asking he can wait for his flight for how long he can stay on airport of Dubai

Comment: `05:00 - 11:55 = 06:55 hours`, are you asking if he can stay or not without a visa for this period?

Comment: Yes sir i m asking this but not for 6:55 hours he will arrive at 5am morning and 2nd flight is at 11:55 stay will be 18:00 hours

Comment: oh sorry I missed the `pm` sign. Just edit your question to include the visa question in it because it is very unclear as it stands now.

Comment: How much he can stay with out Dubai visa on Dubai Airport and he is Ecuador citizen and Pakistani too

Comment: I took the liberty to edit the question based on your comments.

Comment: @Relaxed and I took the liberty to change the title

Comment: Plz tell us fast because sir we still have to buy ticket for Lahore to Dubai and we have already bought ticket for Dubai to Amsterdam to Quito so plz tell how much he can stay on Dubai airport plz tell

Comment: How much he can stay on Dubai airport plz tell this on 7 july

Comment: Plz reply sir and who r u ? R u talking from Dubai airport plz tell this also

Comment: Related question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/31219/transiting-in-dubai-on-back-to-back-return-tickets

Comment: @Malikhassan This is not a chat (nor the hotline for Dubai airport), if someone knows the answer, they will post it in due time. If you need an immediate answer from a service rep, call the airline.

Comment: Which one of the Ecuador and Pakistan passports does he intent to use as his travel document? What is his country of residence?

Comment: Based on the conversation, I believe that this ticket is booked on two different itineraries and two different carriers where the Dubai to Lahore carrier is probably either Emirates or PIA.

Answer (score 4):

Phew! The information on this is not clear at all almost anywhere on the internet. **But** after careful hunting, I have been able to find the relevant tool.

Based on the comments, I was able to understand two things:

- You have already booked a flight from DXB (Dubai) to AMS (Amsterdam) to UIO (Quito)
- You wish to book a flight from Lahore to Dubai which of course would be on a different itinerary, which would make me believe that you will have to ***re-check in your bags***.
- You mentioned 5am which makes me believe that you will be taking [Emirates Flight 623](http://flightaware.com/live/flight/UAE623)

Now, I understand why your questions was initially about the timing, because the transit visa requirements at the Dubai airport are somewhat vague and you *can* apply for a 96-hour transit visa if your transit is greater than 8 hours and of course if you hold an onward ticket.

So, considering your situation, the fact that you will be re-checking in bags is more important than anything else.

If you do have to re-check in your bags, then you **will** need a proper visit visa to enter Dubai otherwise you will not be allowed to do so, possibly not be allowed to board the Lahore to Dubai flight as well. This is well documented by experience from several users on the answers to this question - [Can I through check my bags on separate bookings (international flights)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2173/can-i-through-check-my-bags-on-separate-bookings-international-flights).

Now, if you won't be rechecking in your bags, this situation will be completely different but even then the **time will not matter**.

The Emirates website has a nice tool for finding your necessary [Visa Information](http://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/essential_information/visa_passport_information/find_visa_requirements/find_visa_requirements.aspx). Feeding in the information you presented to us earlier, I was able to obtain [this](http://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/essential_information/visa_passport_information/find_visa_requirements/visa_passport_information_results.aspx?NC=EC&NV=Ecuador&DC=EC&DV=Ecuador&TC=AE%2CNL&TV=United%20Arab%20Emirates%2CNetherlands&h=8c5690ac87d1ef38562c4d9168d88a8a9bcaf58).

So, if you are traveling to Ecuador via Netherlands and Dubai as an Ecuadorian Citizen, and in relation to Dubai,

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>
> **Holders of confirmed onward tickets for a
>   max. transit time of 24 hours.** Visa is required for transit between
>   Dubai International Airport (DXB) and Dubai Al Maktoum International
>   (DWC).
>
> Visa Issuance: **A 96-hour transit visa can be obtained on
>   arrival at Dubai (DXB)**, provided:
>
> - transit time is at least 8 hours; and
> - holding onward ticket to a third country; and
> - holding a passport valid for at least 6 months from date of arrival. Visas are only issued as a part of a transit package together with
>     hotel accommodation and airport transfer.

Also, I would believe this source to be fairly legitimate being on the Emirates website and directly sourced from IATA which is mentioned on the tool.

**In my opinion, your best bet is to get the Emirates ticket and before getting it inquire from Emirates about your situation whether they can re-check in the luggage for you or you can do it without any additional visa requirements.**

Comment: If your luggage is not checked thru then either you'll be required to clear immigration and border control to get to the "other side" or request someone from the airline to do it for you. So if you are doing it, then you're in trouble.

Comment: Haha. Just to be clear, if your nationality permits, it might be possible to utilize TWOV if your transit is less than 24 hours and you don't have to re-check in bags. You will be eligible for a transit visa *if* your transit is greater than 8 hours but this doesn't necessarily mean that you will need one.